How to run vstest.console.exe without adapter in command line?
I have an executable Entrance.exe and a library lib.dll compiled&linked with /PROFILE options (with cl.exe on Windows), Entrance.exe uses functions from lib.dll. Now I want to deploy CI/CD pipelines to collect test coverage data automatically. I want to make use of vstest.console.exe but don't know how to run it with proper options. I tried
vstest.console.exe "Entrance.exe" /InIsolation /EnableCodeCoverage

but it doesn't work, saying no tests found in Entrance.exe.
Actually the executable is neither a test driver nor a test executor, just an executable for normal use. I don't have a specific executable for testing and I don't want to do that. So I wonder if I want to run an executable normally and collect coverage data, how should I use vstest.console.
I ever used llvm, it generates profraw file as long as I run the executable. Can vstest.console achieve this?
I feel that this is possible, since the necessary code pieces to collect coverage data are already injected by the compiler if I assign /PROFILE option to it.
